# 80's illustrated SF book with a toxin mixing spider and a "Balzac-9000"

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a paperback back in the mid 80's all I really remember of it was that it was about a group of beings trapped in a planet.

One of them was a large intelligent spider creature that had poisoned spines that it could mix the toxins to make virtually any chemical, medicine, or poison.

It seemed steam-punky (though such a thing wasn't really on the radar yet) and it also struck me that it had illustrations (5-7) in a trade paperback. Also there was something the main character, a human, had that was named something like the 'Balzac-9000'.

Comment: *Balzac-9000* seems as though it should be easy to Google but I'm getting no hits. How confident are you about that?

Comment: The number, not so much, but I only encountered Balzac years later, discovering to my chagrin that there was a whole hidden meaning in the story that I should have known something about.

Comment: Spider World Series by Colin Wilson? See if book covers ring any bells:  https://www.goodreads.com/series/62815-spider-world